# ¿Como elimino un archivo que fue creado con script Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

El problema es el siguiente: El script que estoy codeando tiene como función crear un archivo de imagen automatizando photoshop via PyAutoGUi. El resultado del script es un archivo png. Lo que quiero lograr es que al finalizar la creacion de la imagen, se elimine ese mismo archivo. El código que estoy utilizando para eliminar el archivo es el siguiente:

```
 import os
    myfile="foto.png"
    if os.path.isfile(myfile):
        os.remove(myfile)
        print("Se ha eliminado correctamente " % myfile)
    else:    
        print("Error: %s no se encontro el archivo" % myfile)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Si corro solo esta parte del codigo como un nuevo script, el archivo se elimina. Pero si agrego este codigo al script que crea la imagen, no elimina el archivo.
¿Alguna idea de donde puede estar el error?

```
os.startfile('contenido.psd')
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.click([174,13])
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click([231,363])
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click([798,190])
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('alt','r')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.hotkey('alt','r','x')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click([480,300])
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click([1031,598])
time.sleep(1)
os.system("taskkill /f /im  Photoshop.exe")

email_user = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
email_password = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
email_send = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

subject = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'blabalabalabl'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

filename='contenido.png'
attachment  =open(filename,'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user,email_password)


server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
server.quit()

Close('contenido.png')
myfile="contenido.png"
time.sleep(15)
if os.path.isfile(myfile):
        os.remove(myfile)
        print("Se ha eliminado correctamente " % myfile)
else:    
        print("Error: %s no se encontro el archivo" % myfile)
```

Comment: ¿Y si usas [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tempfile.html)? Te permite crear archivos temporales que se borran solos al terminar el código.

Comment: Hola Fede, lo que pasa es que estoy creando el archivo de imagen, automatizando photoshop con PyAutoGui. Lo que hace el script es exportar un archivo en forma de png.

Comment: Pues entonces deberías darnos más contexto. Dale a [edit] y pon todo lo necesario para entender el problema. Por otra parte, puede que te esté fallando la ruta: buscas el fichero "foto.png" directamente, sin usar directorios ni nada, por lo que podría estar en otro sitio.

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta, y en cuanto a la ruta del archivo, es correcta, ya que si creo un nuevo script con esa parte del codigo que comparti y lo corró el archivo se elimina correctamente. Igualmente voy a probar agregando la ruta al archivo y te cuento

Comment: Pude identificar el error, y es por que esta siendo utilizado por otro programa el archivo "foto.png". Calculo que debe ser por el mismo script que estoy corriendo. Alguna solucion?

Comment: ¿El archivo lo crea Photoshop y ya está o llega a abrirse en algún momento por el propio script Python después de su creación? Sea como sea debes cerrar el archivo (o el proceso que lo usa) correctamente antes de intentar eliminarlo. Esto pasa típicamente en Python por no llamar a `close`explícitamente (o `with`) y dejar el cierre en manos del GC, pero si el archivo lo maneja Photoshop en tu caso la solución debe estar en él, bien terminando el proceso o haciendo que el programa libere el archivo.

Comment: Me olvide de aclarar, que una vez creado el archivo se envia via e-mail. Ahora modifico el post, disculpen

Comment: visto el código, creo que lo que comenta @FJSevilla debe ser la solución: haces un `open()` pero luego no hay ningún `close()` para liberar el archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como comentaba, abres el archivo pero nunca lo cierras explícitamente. Esto causa que cuando tu script intenta eliminarlo con `os.remove(myfile)`, el sistema operativo informa que no es posible porque el archivo está siendo usado actualmente por un proceso, tu propio script de hecho.

Llama al método `close` de forma explícita una vez que no necesites más el archivo:

```
attachment = open(filename,'rb')
part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
attachment.close()
os.remove(filename)
```

o mejor usa el manejador de contexto con `with`, una vez ejecutado el código encerrado en el bloque liberará el archivo automáticamente sin que tengas que llamar a `close` manualmente:

```
part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')

with open(filename,'rb') as attachment:
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())

os.remove(filename)
```

Un archivo que no es cerrado explícitamente eventualmente será liberado por el recolector de basura, pero nunca sabes de forma determinista cuando esto va a ocurrir. Por eso, es una buena práctica cerrar siempre todo archivo abierto de forma explícita en cuanto deja de ser necesario.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias  FjSevilla y  fedorqui ! pude resolverlo. Saludos!